# C# - Is it possible to Sign hash using RSA SHA512?

Tags: c#, hash, .net-4.0, sha

I have created a selfsign certificate using OpenSSL as follows:

`openssl req -x509 -sha512 -new keyrsa:2048 -keyout key2.pem -out cert2.pem -days 100`

`openssl pkcs12 -export -out pkcs12_cert_test2.pfx -inkey key2.pem -in cert2.pem`

I have installed `pkcs12_cert_test2.pfx` on Windows and the certificate sign algorithm value is `sha512RSA`

Then, I have coded the following in C# .NET 4.0:

```
public static bool DSHandler(string operation, string path, string devicePath)
{
    bool result = false;
        CryptoConfig.AddAlgorithm(typeof(USBSaferAppEFB.RsaPkCs1Sha512SignatureDescription),
            "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha512");
        string password = "xxxx";
        bool validSignature = false;
        byte[] hashchain = generateHash(path);
        string digSignFile = Utils.RegVarValue(DIGSIGNFILE);
        string subjectDN = Utils.RegVarValue(SUBJECTDN);

        if (operation == "sign")
        {
            byte[] signature = SignFromContainer(hashchain, subjectDN);
            if (signature != null)
            {
                string signaturestring = Convert.ToBase64String(signature);

                File.WriteAllBytes(devicePath + digSignFile, signature);
                result = true;
            }
            else
                result = false;
        }
}

static byte[] SignFromContainer(byte[] hashchain, string certSubject)
{
    try
    {
        X509Store my = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        my.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = null;
        foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in my.Certificates)
        {
            if (cert.Subject.Contains(certSubject))
            {
                // We found it.
                // Get its associated CSP and private key
                csp = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;
            }
        }

        if (csp == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        byte[] myHash = { 59,4,248,102,77,97,142,201,
        210,12,224,93,25,41,100,197,
        210,12,224,93};

        // Sign the hash
        return csp.SignHash(hashchain, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA-512"));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        log.Logger("Exception: "+e.Message, "debug");
        log.Logger(e.StackTrace, "debug");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Using solutions from some articles and answers, I have `RsaPkCs1Sha512SignatureDescription` class where I try to implement and register the signature description:

```
public class RsaPkCs1Sha512SignatureDescription : SignatureDescription
{
    public RsaPkCs1Sha512SignatureDescription()
    {
        KeyAlgorithm = typeof(RSACryptoServiceProvider).FullName;
        DigestAlgorithm = typeof(SHA512Managed).FullName;
        FormatterAlgorithm = typeof(RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter).FullName;
        DeformatterAlgorithm = typeof(RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter).FullName;
    }

    public override AsymmetricSignatureDeformatter CreateDeformatter(AsymmetricAlgorithm key)
    {
        var sigProcessor = (AsymmetricSignatureDeformatter)CryptoConfig.CreateFromName(DeformatterAlgorithm);
        sigProcessor.SetKey(key);
        sigProcessor.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA-512");
        return sigProcessor;
    }

    public override AsymmetricSignatureFormatter CreateFormatter(AsymmetricAlgorithm key)
    {
        var sigProcessor =
            (AsymmetricSignatureFormatter)CryptoConfig.CreateFromName(FormatterAlgorithm);
        sigProcessor.SetKey(key);
        sigProcessor.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA-512");
        return sigProcessor;
    }
}
```

I have verified that hash is `64` bytes long and it returns a `CryptographicException: Bad Hash`. But if I use `myHash` var (20 bytes long), although algorithm specified in `SignHash` is `SHA512`, it works, and sign the hash using `SHA1` algorithm.

Also, if I print `csp.SignatureAlgorithm`, its value is http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1. Why is signature algorithm equals to http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1 if the detail of the installed certificate shows `sha512RSA` as sign algorithm? Could be this point the real problem? If so, how could I create the certificate properly? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. It is not necessary to implement `RsaPkCs1Sha512SignatureDescription` class or something similiar but to specify the right CSP to allow CryptoAPI to use SHA256 or SHA512: "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider", type 24.

We only need to put CSP type as CspParameter and export/import key info:

```
    byte[] privateKeyBlob;
    CspParameters cp = new CspParameters(24);
    RSACryptoServiceProvider csp = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;
    privateKeyBlob = csp.ExportCspBlob(true);
    csp = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cp);
    csp.ImportCspBlob(privateKeyBlob); 

    // Sign the hash
    return csp.SignHash(hashchain, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA-512"));
```

Comment: I'm kinda a noob in this regard and I'm attempting to do the same thing so I have a few follow-up questions: 1. What is the namespace of cert.PrivateKey. 2. How is the private key originally assigned to cert.PrivateKey? 3. Why export and then reimport the Blob--shouldn't the first csp object created be sufficient?

Answer (score 5):

This process has been simplified in .NET 4.6:

```
byte[] signature;

using (RSA rsa = cert.GetRSAPrivateKey())
{
    signature = rsa.SignHash(hash, HashAlgorithmName.SHA512, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
}
```

Note that the .NET 4.6 RSA type no longer requires casting to RSACryptoServiceProvider, and if you use GetRSAPrivateKey() (instead of the PrivateKey property) the returned object is likely to handle SHA-512 signature generation.  GetRSAPrivateKey also returns a unique object each time, so you should Dispose it appropriately.